# If I don't have access to chat and a post requires a lot of back-and-forth what should I do?

Tags: discussion, comments, chat

I understand that we do not want to get into lengthy comment exchanges, but many times when working with a less than experienced user I have had to use the comments to help them ([as in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260769/php-button-to-delete-item-from-mysql)) get to where they need to be.

The reason that I have to use the comments is because the system that I work from during the day ***blocks chat***. In addition it turns out the OP did / does not have enough rep to enter chat.

Should I go back to the conversation after the user has been satisfied and remove my comments? It seems that would confuse things. Should I supply the user with an e-mail address that I can communicate with them through for the problem? That seems it would open another can of worms. (Anecdotally I, and others, have had our e-mail addresses tracked down by users because we have provided enough information in our profiles to let anyone with reasonable knowledge have clues.)

How do you handle this if you cannot access chat?

Comment: If the problem requires a lot of personalized back and forth between you and the author to solve then the question isn't suitable for SO.  It's probably too broad of a question.

Comment: In this case @Servy the question wasn't too broad - it was the solution that ended up being broad (because PHP) and caused a lot of questions on the OP's part. If the right answer is too broad should it be avoided?

Comment: If you cannot provide a correct and high quality answer to the question in a reasonable scope, then it's too broad.  If the question could have been reasonably answered concisely, correctly, and in a helpful manor and an answer simply failed to accomplish that, then the question is not too broad.

Comment: Even if the question *is* too broad (and you've voted accordingly), remains the possibility of trying to help the OP hammer out an improved question. Chat seems to me appropriate for this. I've actually run into a situation like Jay mentions recently. The question was not too broad but the OP needed a bit of hand-holding with my answer. (First said it did not work but did not try it correctly. Then found an imaginary problem with it.) I ignored the suggestion to go into chat but at some point it could have been warranted.

Comment: I would have been glad to go into chat @Louis, but cannot do so from my day computer.

Comment: i'd say leave the comment chain, unless it's drawing attention away from the question/answer, otherwise, go ahead and clear out your comments or flag for a mod to clean them out as irrelevant or not constructive.

Comment: I suspect your employer or supervisor can give you an unambiguous answer :)

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yeah, I got that. :)

Comment: They don't mind (actually encourage) SO - but they cannot get the IT Dept off of top-dead-center on what they consider to be "bad" @HansPassant :)

Comment: I've gotten around such problems in the past by using the FoxyProxy extension on Firefox to send requests to a problematic site through a proxy running off of one of my servers. FWIW.